# Alternative to jumpToPage or animateToPage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two layer in pageview as following :

PageView
'->PageView
'->PageView

Parent PageView scrolls vertically, while children pageview scrolls horizontally.

Expectation:
Suppose there are three pages in child pageview and when i scroll horizontally in first pageview which moves to second page and then scroll vertically to move to second pageview then it also should at second page.

Actual:
I have used two pageController for child pageview, as i scroll the pageview, OnPageChanged function is called where controller.jumpToPage() is been written, which cancels the animation.
I dont wont to cancel the animation as it will change next pageview page.

```
PageView(
  children:[
    PageView(....),
    PageView(....)
  ]
)
```

Tried something like above code.